# From a list<object> , ToString() them just when they are primitive types or have this method overriden

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, tostring

Given a list of objects, I'd like to print a string version of them just in case the object.ToString() result is a relevant string.

By that I mean I don't want to get things like:

```
obj.ToString() -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyLib.Dude]  
obj.ToString() -> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.DateTime]
obj.ToString() -> System.Byte[]
```

But I want to get things like:

```
obj.ToString() -> Hi
obj.ToString() -> 129847.123
obj.ToString() -> Id = 123
```

What should be the best way to implement this in a method:

```
Public Sub PrintInterestingStuffOnly(ByVal coolList as Ilist(Of Object))
    For Each obj in coolList
        'insert solution here
        Console.WriteLine( ....
    End For
End Sub
```

?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is to test whether obj.ToString() == obj.GetType().ToString()

Comment: How can you tell it's relevant? Do you have specific rules defined on what to do in each case? For example, when no ToString() is overriden?

Comment: @decyclone It's not relevant to me if the result of the ToString() is trash like "System.blablabla", "[Proxy187321812]", or things like that.

Comment: My question is what would you show instead when it's not relevant?

Comment: @decyclone Just skipping not relevant stuff would be enough, since I can't be overriding tostring for all the classes involved. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
foreach (var item in coolList)
{
    Type t = item.GetType();
    if (t.IsPrimitive
        || (t.GetMethod("ToString", bf, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null) != null))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

This could be slow since it uses reflection to determine whether or not a particular type has overridden the `ToString` method. A faster alternative might be to use a static cache to "remember" the result of the reflection so that it only needs to be done once per type:

```
foreach (var item in coolList)
{
    Type t = item.GetType();
    if (t.IsPrimitive || _cache.GetOrAdd(t, _factory))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

// ...

private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, bool> _cache =
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, bool>();

private const BindingFlags _flags =
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

private static readonly Func<Type, bool> _factory =
    t => t.GetMethod("ToString", _flags, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null) != null;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Join(", ", list);
```

If the list was composed of `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`, This will print out:

> 1, 2, 3, 4

(It will perform the `.ToString()` implicitly, so you can use any sort of object.)

Answer (score 0):

```
If Not obj.ToString().StartsWith("System.") Then
```